# Parse id in URL in encrypted form to prevent sql injection

Tags: parsing, url, encryption

snatching my hair to fix this problem but I can't.

I am parsing id in url to pull data on next page according to that id. So rather than parsing `id=123` I encrypted it something like `process.php?token=TG4n6iv_aoO7sU3AngFY4WLSppLvueEoh-MnYE6k7NA`, and decrypted it on process.php page by collecting it with `$_GET`, before using it in sql query. This is not proper URL, I need url like `process.php?token=9878799889` and I need to decrypt this 9878799889 on process.php which would give me my original user id.

So here I can not use md5 or base64_encode which give me ugly string.
What would be best thing to do here?
id is unique so generated long digits should be unique as well and not easy to guess.
Right now I am using encrypt logarithm with salt. Actually want to parse like `www.sitename.com/process/token/9878799889`..this can be achieve with .htaccess so not worried about it..

Any help will be much appreciated..

Comment: You can use something like [crc32()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) to generate a numeric hash, but even the PHP manual recommends `md5()` instead. Will you explain more fully why you cannot use md5?

Comment: thanks George, md5 will give me ugly string which is I am already using right now thats why I dont want to use it

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add an association table in your databse, which would contains a UUID as primary key (a randomly generated number) and your true ID reference 
(and other information you may want to store there, like a "valid until" date or other things...)

You'd have to generate the entry in that table as you parse the UUID
let's say `INSERT INTO uuid_table (uuid, real_id) VALUES (9878799889, 123);`
now when you process the url `process.php?token=9878799889`
you would only have to `SELECT real_id FROM uuid_table WHERE uuid=9878799889;`
it would retern the read id `123`

You should also `DELETE FROM uuid_table WHERE uuid=9878799889` when you're done.

Note that it would also work with md5 or base_64, but indeed it makes the url uglier.

Comment: I am also considering load on server, this will double the request and when 2000 or more user accessing same database and may be at the same time, it will show impact on page loading..isn't it?

Comment: actually, you would only need those 3 requests, + 1 update per thread to tell that each thread processed the thing correctly.
When you select the id, let's say 123, you can process this one and the 14 following.
The next insert would have to be 138, and so on...
Moreover, some validation would be needed to be sure you didn't miss any id (in the case of thread crashing, or whatever else)

Comment: Thanks Mash sounds like problem could be solved with your solution but it's not secure 100%. Do you think is there any problem with token which I am using currently? like process.php?token=TG4n6iv_aoO7sU3AngFY4WLSppLvueEoh-MnYE6k7NA Its like security vs html friendly URL